# JQuery UI draggable element position is reset after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a draggable div that I want to be able to drag and drop into a droppable div.

Once dropped, it should no longer be draggable and it should be positioned at the center of the droppable div.

I got that working, but I now want to add an AJAX request when the div is dropped.  If the AJAX call is successful then the draggable div should no longer be draggable and be positioned at the center of the droppable div.

With my current code, when I add the AJAX call, everything works ok and then the droppable div gets put back to where it started.  Does anyone know how I can stop this happening?

I have a demo of the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulkerrison/K6SZG/3/)

The code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="playingArea" class="droppable">Drop in here</div>

<div id="player" class="draggable">Drag Me</div>
```

CSS

```
#playingArea{
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#player{
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        containment : 'document',
        cursor : 'move',
        revert : true
    });

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept : '.draggable',
        hoverClass : 'hovered',
        drop : handleDrop
    });
})

function handleDrop(event, ui) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/echo/json/",
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(data, errorThrown) {
            alert('request failed :' + errorThrown);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            positionBox(event, ui);
        }
    });
}

function positionBox(event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
    ui.draggable.position({
        of : $("#playingArea"),
        my : 'center',
        at : 'center'
    });
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    $("#player").css({
        opacity : 1
    })
    alert("looks ok now - but it won't stay here");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted in the end, just had to set the revert to "invalid" rather than true:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    containment : 'document',
    cursor : 'move',
    revert : "invalid"
});
```

and then remove the revert option in the positionBox function.  I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulkerrison/K6SZG/11/) to reflect the solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the attribute `revert` to `false`

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    containment : 'document',
    cursor : 'move',
    revert : false
});
```

Comment: I set it to true initially so that if the user drags it anywhere other than the droppable div it reverts back to its original position.  After the div is dropped, it calls into the handleDrop function which does an AJAX call then calls positionBox which sets revert to false: ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);  This works on it's own, but when I introduce the AJAX call, it stops working.